# Using dbReadTable in_schema

Tags: r, sql-server, database, rodbc

I'm trying to use dbReadTable , however my tables sit under a schema inside the database.

For example using the code below I can connect:

```
  db_ANZSCO <- tbl(con, in_schema("BGVIEW" ,"ANZSCO"))
```

But when I try to use dbReadTable I get the following error;

```
  dbReadTable(con, "ANZSCO"))  

   Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "ANZSCO"'
     nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server      Driver][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'ANZSCO', database 'BurningGlass', schema 'dbo'.
```

I understand  the table is sitting under a schema but I have no idea how to access using dbReadTable, I did try to look into documentation but I have been so far unsuccessful.

Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the new-ish `DBI::Id()` function, that accepts the schema name and table name as separate arguments.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(), dsn = "qqqq") # Replace `qqqq`.
a <- DBI::Id(
  schema  = "BGVIEW",
  table   = "ANZSCO"
)
ds <- DBI::dbReadTable(con, a)
DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

If that doesn't work, please paste the table definition in your question, and the code that creates the connection.  You've tagged your question with [`[rodbc]`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RODBC), but it looks likes you're using the newer & DBI-compliant [odbc](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=odbc) package.

See also

- The 'Schema Support' section of https://www.r-dbi.org/blog/dbi-2-final/
- https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3452
- https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/191

Comment: Tks for your response, I did not understand the creation of the object a then using a s inside ds.. What is the use of a?

Comment: sorry, try now.  I transferred the wrong line of code into the browser.

Comment: Tks a lot, I have a quick question if you don't mind. What does the id does?

Comment: I can't explain it as well as the authors of the three links under 'See also' above.  The best short summary is probably from that 'Schema Support' section: ["The new `Id()` function constructs identifiers. All arguments must be named, yet DBI doesn’t specify the argument names, because DBMS have an inconsistent notion of namespaces."](https://www.r-dbi.org/blog/dbi-2-final/)

Comment: Fails miserably with an error message like: `Could not create execute: SELECT * from """BGVIEW"".""ANZSCO"""`.

Comment: "miserably" might be too strong.  I saw the `Id()` function was modified recently.  Maybe check out the [recent release page](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/releases/tag/v1.1.0) and the [issues](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/issues).  Especially `dbUnquoteIdentifier()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
df <- dbReadTable(con, c("BGVIEW" ,"ANZSCO")))
```